# ASP.NET web service maximum array length quota

Tags: asp.net, web-services, maxstringcontentlength, service-model

I'm gettingg this error in an ASP.NET web service whene recieving a file on the client:

```
The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.
```

I know how to fix this for a WCF service. But where do I have to change `maxArrayLength` or `maxStringContentLength` in a ASP.NET web service?

**Edit:**

In my web.config (server) there is nothing specific to the web service.

this is my binding in app.config (client):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="OMCServiceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/1820/Service/OMCService.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OMCServiceSoap"
        contract="ServiceReference.OMCServiceSoap" name="OMCServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Are you sure this error is happening on the sever, and not the client?  It looks like the problem is on the reading side.

Comment: @jlew. Yep. you are right. it's on the client.

Comment: So is your client using a service reference or a web reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="OMCServiceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/1820/Service/OMCService.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OMCServiceSoap"
    contract="ServiceReference.OMCServiceSoap" name="OMCServiceSoap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I couldn't find this because of my empty binding tag. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

under  `<system.serviceModel>` like below

```
    <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
                 <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
 </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: `basicHttpBinding` element does not have a `readerQuotas` child element.